# C# Firebird fill Datatable using FbDataAdapter fails

Tags: c#, datatable, firebird

I'm trying to get a `DataTable` filled with Data from a firebird database.
But it fails at the point `da.Fill(ds, "Result");`

The error message is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Execute requires the Command object to have a Transaction object when the Connection object assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction. The Transaction property of the Command has not been initialized.

```cs
try
{
   FbTransaction transaction = Fbconnection.BeginTransaction();
   FbCommand command = new FbCommand(Fbsql, Fbconnection, transaction);
   FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(Fbsql, Fbconnection);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds, "Result");
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Result"];
   this.CloseConnection();
   return dt;
}
```

Any help on how to get this working is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this?

Comment: Hi Mark, If read some where that the way Firebird (or maybe the connection between C# and firebird) requires this to be just a little bit diffrent than the way MySQL would do this. What you see here is a "translation/adaption" from the MySQL method.
The article I found is here: http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_adonet/firebird_adonet.html#dataset_fill.

Comment: An SSCCE is self-contained: a simple program that demonstrates the error, because if I look at the code of the Firebird .NET provider then this error can only occur in very specific circumstancesT. Also be aware that IBProvider (which you link to), is not the same as the Firebird .NET provider (which - based on the exception message - is what you use).

Comment: Hi Mark, Ok, I do use the Firebird .NET provider. And for various reasons, I can't make a sscce. Would it be possible to give me an example of how you would fill a data set with the Firebird .NET provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a closer look at the code, you are creating a `FbCommand` and a transaction that you aren't actually using. Now when you execute the `FbDataAdapter`, the Firebird .NET provider notices the connection is already using a transaction and throws the exception.

You need to change your code either to:

```
FbTransaction transaction = Fbconnection.BeginTransaction();
FbCommand command = new FbCommand(Fbsql, Fbconnection, transaction);
FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(command);
```

Or without using an explicit separate transaction:

```
FbDataAdapter da = new FbDataAdapter(Fbsql, Fbconnection);
```

BTW: I'd strongly suggest you apply `using` to objects that are disposable, to be sure resources are cleaned up properly.

Comment: Hoi Mark, dank je wel voor je geduld en antwoord.
Ik heb de bovenste methode nu in gebruik.
Maar weet niet hoe je de "using" functie gebruikt.Dus wellicht heb je daar nog tips of info over?

Comment: @user3058288 You're welcome. English is the language of choice on StackOverflow :) Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx, in essence you wrap all objects implementing `IDisposable` in a `using` block. This ensures the object is properly closed and disposed off before the scope is exited.